# Как правильно написать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить содержимое тега с атрибутом id="content"?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

http://code.mu/exercises/advanced/php/parsing/parsing-sajtov-regulyarnymi-vyrazeniyami-php/2/1.php

```
<?php 
$str =  
file_get_contents('http://code.mu/exercises/advanced/php/parsing/parsing- 
sajtov-regulyarnymi-vyrazeniyami-php/2/1.php'); 

preg_match_all('#<[^>]*id\s*=\s*["\']\s*content\s*["\'].*?>(<.*?>.*?</.*? 
>)*</.*?>[^<]*#su', $str, $res);

//var_dump($str);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

Comment: Правильно будет не писать регулярное выражение, а использовать нормальный парсер html. http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#<.*?id.*?=.*?"content".*?>(.*?)<#isu', $str, $res);
```

как то так